# What is the meaning this PHP expression?

Tags: php

I really can't figure out what this PHP expression means, could someone please tell me what the point of it is?

```
if(preg_match(“/\d{5}-\d{4}/”, $number))
```

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php yet that code won't run with `“`'s.

Comment: Stack deals with problematic code, not code that you don't understand. It's not a school.

Answer (score 1):

This is a regular expression intended to test for the presence of a five digit string, followed by a dash and then four more digits - like a US postal code.

It will match for:

```
12345-0987
Some text 12345-0987
Words 12345-0987 more
```

Because there are no anchors

To validate a zip code, use:

```
preg_match("/^\d{5}-\d{4}$/", $number)
```

Which will only match a nine-digit zip

Answer (score 0):

\d is short for [0-9]. So this expression matches any string with 5 digits followed by a - and four digits

Answer (score 0):

preg_match searches the subject argument you pass ($number) for a pattern which you pass as a regular expression '/\d{5}-\d{4}/'.

The regular expression is a pattern formed out of numbers, letters and symbols which can refer to a range of characters in a string.

The point of this statement is to basically check a string to see if it contains a range of strings.